# My G String wears out all the time

Tags: guitar, strings, maintenance

I use Elixir HD light on my Yamaha SLG200S.  I notice my G string is usually the first to develop kinks / gets frayed.  Of course, when I change, I change the whole set.  Is there a setup issue with my guitar or is this a common phenomenon? BTW, My guitar is highly playable and holds tuning very well.

Comment: I understand you mean S**L**G200S?

Comment: Consider how hard you are fretting the strings during playing. most of us press harder than needed. The object is to make a clean sound, not to wring the guitar's neck! If you still have to press *really* hard, it's maybe because the action needs fettling.

Comment: ROFL reading the bit about not wringing the neck.  Rest assured I want my guitar alive . 

SLG200 has a higher action than my Yamaha Pacifica and I use heavier acoustic strings on them. 

Thanks for the info, though.  This case might just be what leftaroundabout was saying:  old strings.

Comment: I just addressed this same issue a few days ago. https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/98315/solution-for-a-more-durable-acoustic-guitar-g-string?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty common for the wound G string on a steelstring guitar to be the first point of failure, as it has a really thin core and is right in the middle and thus always in the way of strumming. Many guitarists just accept this, and simply replace strings every week anyway.

If that's the case for you, then certainly consider switching to some cheaper strings. Elixir are, I would say, more for gentle long-life playing.

You could also consider switching to an unwound G-string, perhaps even an electric string set. Arguably, the whole point of unwieldy bronze acoustic strings is to project more volume, but on a *silent guitar* that's completely irrelevant.

However, the bridge may need adjustment since an unwound G-string has a different intonation behaviour.

Comment: Thank you! I will update the number of hours the strings were used tomorrow to get feedback on whether it’s reasonable timeframe to change.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it was the 1st string  or D string that was most worn on my guitar because they are the thinner strings with the biggest tension.

I never replaced the whole set because the others were still useful. The sellers could hear my protest when they wanted me to buy a whole set and I needed only one string!